# sql, python (tkinter)

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, tkinter

Дамы и господа, прошу не судить строго, т.к. начинающий.
Делаю запрос в базу, что бы вытащить все значения label из таблицы.
Затем эти значения, мне надо подставить в элемент combobox.
В целом, все работает, но результат в combobox весь в фигурных скобках {} (скрин и код прилагаю). Подскажите, куда копать? Заранее благодарю.

Пример функции:

```
def label_divisions_on_combobox():
    all_labels = []
    with sqlite3.connect('db/tournament.db') as db:
        cursor = db.cursor()
        query = """SELECT label FROM divisions"""
        cursor.execute(query)
        all_labels = list(cursor)
        for all_labels in list(cursor):
            return all_labels[0] if all_labels else ''
    return all_labels
```

Сам комбобокс:

```
label_division_combobox = ttk.Combobox(for_division_menu, values=label_divisions_on_combobox())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]. Как от них избавиться

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)